# Awk, System() function, interacting with shell

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list farm.txt:

```
cow
chicken
horse
pig
```

I have the following string of comma separated values, assigned to the variable $header in BASH:

```
animal,food_type,food_amount,feed_time
```

Finally, I have a file care.csv which contains data about the care of each of these animals:

```
cow,hay,2,12:00
cow,grain,3,12:00
chicken,corn,1000,11:00
pig,slop,76,04:00
horse,apple,1,23:00
...
```

I use AWK to take each word in farm.txt and use it to create a new .csv file of the format "[animal]_care.csv".

```
awk -F '\r' 'NR > 1 { system("touch " $1"_care.csv") }' farm.txt
```

This script works up to this point. I get the output I expect:

```
cow_care.csv
chicken_care.csv
horse_care.csv
pig_care.csv
```

What I want to do now is to use awk again to cycle through care.csv, and assign each row to the appropriate [animal]_care.csv file. Here is what I am trying:

```
awk -F ',' '{ system("echo " $0 " >> " $1 "_stale.csv") }' care.csv
```

But this is not working. Finally, I want to put the string $header at the beginning of each [anima]_care.csv file.

I'm stumped, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [redirect the output of `print` to a file](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html):

```
awk -F, '{file=$1"_stale.csv"; print $0 >> file; close(file)}' care.csv
```

`system()` is not required here. Don't miss to close the file, otherwise you might end up with "too many open file descriptors" depending on the number of lines in `care.csv`.

If you want to print the headers as well, use:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{header=$0; next} # Save the header on the first line
     {file=$1"_stale.csv"; print header > file; print $0 >> file; close(file)}
' care.csv
```

This assumes that the headers are on top of `care.csv`. If you want to pass the headers via the commandline use:

```
awk -F, -v header="$header" \
  '{file=$1"_stale.csv"; print header > file; print $0 >> file; close(file)}' care.csv
```

Comment: Your solution is working as advertised, with the exception of adding in the headers. I can't get the header inserted into the top of the file using either solution.

Comment: I think this will print the header multiple times, before each line.

Comment: @user3285817 Sorry, I missed a `=`. It should be `NR==1` not `NR=1`. Now it works for me

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add the header, assuming the file is sorted by animal names

```
$ awk -F, -v h="$header" 'p!=$1{print h > $1"_stale.csv"; p=$1}
                               {print > $1"_stale.csv"}' care.csv

$ tail *stale.csv

==> chicken_stale.csv <==
animal,food_type,food_amount,feed_time
chicken,corn,1000,11:00

==> cow_stale.csv <==
animal,food_type,food_amount,feed_time
cow,hay,2,12:00
cow,grain,3,12:00

==> horse_stale.csv <==
animal,food_type,food_amount,feed_time
horse,apple,1,23:00

==> pig_stale.csv <==
animal,food_type,food_amount,feed_time
pig,slop,76,04:00
```

if the file is not sorted simply change the first block to

```
!($1 in a){print h > $1"_stale.csv"; a[$1]}
```

Comment: make sure you sort care.csv first!